# i filtered out observations not equal to 0, but when i use facet wrap, it ignores it

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to filter specifically for each graph on the grid?

I do not want the chart to show empty slots, the chart shows normally when i display the plot for individal years. However, when i try to display a facet grip by year, all charts include empty spaces which i do not want. I tried using

```
which(trade$value>0)
```

but that didnt work.

Here is my plot

```
trade%>%filter(countries !='World',value !=0)%>%
  ggplot(aes(x='',y=value,fill=factor(countries)),color='black')+
  geom_col(width=1)+
  geom_text(aes(label=countries),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=dollar)+
  coord_polar(theta = 'y',start=0)+
  facet_wrap(~year,ncol=3)+
  labs(fill='Countries',title = 'Dairy products imported' )
```

[image: Facet grid]

It is showing those unfilled portions which i do not want for each of the charts.

Sample data

```
1                     World 2010 463000
2                    France 2010 145000
3               New Zealand 2010 191000
4  United States of America 2010 126000
5                   Denmark 2010      0
6                   Ireland 2010      0
7       Trinidad and Tobago 2010      0
8                     World 2011 525000
9                    France 2011 266000
10              New Zealand 2011 122000
```

it shows normally for each year while not using the facet grid
[image]

Comment: The issue is that when using `facet_wrap` you get the same limits for each facets. In your case the limits are set according to the range of values in year 2013 (That's why you get a full pie for this year). For all other years you end up with "empty" spaces. The default way to tackle this would be to free the scales which however (TBMK) does not work with coord_polar. Two options: First. Standardize your data by computing percentage shares for each year. Second. Make separate plots for each year and glue them together using e.g. `patchwork`.

Comment: i also tried to set the scales to free, but polar_coord doesnt allow free scales, i've found the same problem here https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2815

Comment: Have you tried using `filter(countries !='World' & value !=0)` instead of `filter(countries !='World',value !=0)`?

Comment: same problem Jonathan

Comment: As far as I get it the workaround offered in the issue you linked should solve your problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: tried it, but got error: Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
Error: stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. by modifying the coord_polar function to allow free scales it is possible

```
my_cp<-coord_polar(theta = 'y')
my_cp$is_free <- function()TRUE
```

also, i was missing `stat='identity` in the `geom_col` parameters which was causing some other errors.

so by setting the scales parameter in coord_polar to free, it will clear up the problem

```
facet_wrap(~year,ncol=3,scales='free')+
```

[image]

thanks to https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2815

Now i will just have to tidy up the mess lol